# how to fix Scapy.all has no attribute for arp in kali linux?

Tags: python, linux, pycharm, scapy

how to fix this please
i have tried to install necessary tools to the virtualenv it's still the same
i tried to download scapy on linux terminal, still the same

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import scapy.all as scapy


def scan(ip):
    arp_request = scapy.ARP(pdst=ip)
    print(arp_request.summary())
    scapy.ls(scapy.ARP())

scan("192.168.43.1/24")
```

OUTPUT:

```
root@Webhead:~/PycharmProjects/network_scanner# python network_scanner.py 

    ARP who has ?? says ??
    hwtype     : XShortField                         = 1               (1)
    ptype      : XShortEnumField                     = 2048            (2048)
    hwlen      : FieldLenField                       = None            (None)
    plen       : FieldLenField                       = None            (None)
    op         : ShortEnumField                      = 1               (1)
    hwsrc      : MultipleTypeField                   = '08:00:27:23:ff:90' ``(None)
    psrc       : MultipleTypeField                   = '192.168.43.183' (None)
    hwdst      : MultipleTypeField                   = '00:00:00:00:00:00' `(None)
    pdst       : MultipleTypeField                   = '0.0.0.0'       (None)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do with this code. But the output seems to match your code.
Scapy is installed, and performs as expected

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem.
After typing: `pip install --upgrade scapy` it's worked.